# Python *args vs single <tuple> argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, tuples, args

I have to pass reference (or call, no matter...) stack between methods.
I wrote the code and pay attention on next. What's better to use?

This?

```
def _process_value(value, *ref_stack):
    # Do something... BTW, I need to add (or return) value from cache
    # according to ref_stack         
    _process_value(value, *ref_stack + (ref_key,))
```

Or next?

```
def _process_value(value, ref_stack):
    # Do something...
    _process_value(value, ref_stack + (ref_key,))
```

Does have any of these memory, speed issues or some bounds?
Thanks

Comment: The `*args` version will have to create a new tuple out of the argument tuple, this means that its call-time is not constant. However if `ref_stack` has few elements(less then something like 100-200) there wont be a big difference between the two.

Comment: ref_stack + (ref_key,) also requires to create a new tuple for every level. how deep does this go? for small tuple lengths, no issue, but another data structure like `deque` is a more natural choice for a stack. dunno what the actual memory/perf differences would be.

Comment: The best way to answer this question would be to actually profile. Changing between the *args and the tuple (or even the deque) version should be fairly simple in code. I would recommend using the %timeit magic function in ipython as an easy way to do this.

Comment: Thanks to all, and I know about python timeit:) but I hope to here some expert comments or notes from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no arbitrary limit on the size of the `*ref_stack` argument: the following code will run until it's out of memory (or, if you're like me, until you kill it because you're bored waiting for your swap file):

```
def foo(*args):
    print(len(args))
    foo(*args + args)
```

Assuming that `ref_stack` isn't reassigned in the function, if you're concerned about performance and memory then the obvious (to me) thing to try is a list, with code like this:

```
def _process_value(value, ref_stack):
    # ...
    ref_stack.append(ref_key)
    _process_value(value, ref_stack)
    ref_stack.pop()
    # ...
```

Or, if your function really is tail-recursive as it appears, you don't need the pop and for that matter you don't need the recursive call:

```
def _process_value(value, ref_stack):
    while True:
        # ...
        ref_stack.append(ref_key)
```